# ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64 not installing alongside windows 8

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-8

i am trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows 8 but as soon as i choose the option install inside windows 8
it shows a black screen with this written on it:

```
acpid: exiting
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
*Asking all remaining processes to terminate...
```

then it asks me to remove the cd drive n press enter
then it restarts n again windows 8 is booted directly

secure boot is disabled and it cant be enabled

any solutions???

Comment: did the installation complete successfully and this happens or before the completion of installation?

Comment: If the installation had completed then the issue is "The win+ ubuntu" UEFI issue due to which you dont see grub on reboot and you dont have to worry about the error message.See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069

Comment: installion didnt complete


as soon as i pressed next after choosing install alongside windows 8
this thing happens!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to worry about this error message

Open the terminal and edit the file `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` using nano (or any text editor) as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

Inside the file change the `RUN` property to `yes`, so the file will  become:

```
# Defaults for the speech-dispatcher initscript, from speech-dispatcher

# Set to yes to start system wide Speech Dispatcher
RUN=yes
```

Press <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano

Comment: by opening the terminal u mean cmd?

Comment: @BharatSharma Did the installation complete??

Comment: NO
it happens when i choose install alongside windows 8 n press next

Comment: then the  above solution wont work for you

Comment: then wat should i do???

Comment: @BharatSharma are you instaling it from inside the windows using wubi?

Comment: no
i am using a boot cd n booting it from the start

Answer (score 0):

You must not install Ubuntu inside Windows 8. There are changes in Windows 8 that makes this very unsafe. You have to perform a real installation if you want to dual-boot Ubuntu and Win8.

Comment: wat do u mean by a real installation?

Comment: There's something called Wubi that will install Ubuntu on a Windows file system. It's never been very good, but on Windows 8 it's very unsafe because Windows 8 doesn't shut down properly. So you need to create a new partition and install Ubuntu on that, rather than inside the Windows file system.